# How can static plot in gnuplot be converted to recieve updated data?

Tags: plot, mapping, gnuplot, coordinate-systems

The aim is to recrate the plot given in the 'gnuplot demo pages' :
make it read data from a data file: txt/csv/dat
when the data/file is updated; the plot updates accordingly..
ie data is added to data file evey 10mins
additional how can processed in a way that only the most recent update in the data file is plotted not the entire feed of data?

.. so is there another way?

My attempts of creating what I thought would be straight forward..hit the wall; all input will be welcome.
I try adding:
 `plot [0:100] '< head -1 file.dat' using 1:6 with points`

***this doesn't output data using the given format.

Above that line of code I then include/ tried:

```
f(x) = (x == stats_max ? 1:0)
as above....plot "mydatafile.somformat'
pause 3 reread
```

the message returned was stats cannot be used with polar data

original code given below:

````
set zzeroaxis; set xzeroaxis; set yzeroaxis
set xyplane at 0
unset border
unset key
unset xtics
unset ytics
set ztics axis

set arrow 1 from 0,0,0 to 1,0,0 head filled lw 1.5
set label 1 at 1.2,0,0 "X" center
set arrow 2 from 0,0,0 to 0,1,0 head filled lw 1.5
set label 2 at 0,1.2,0 "Y" center
set arrow 3 from 0,0,0 to 0,0,21 head filled lw 1.5
set label 3 at 0,0,23 "Z" center

set view 60, 30, 1., 1.75

set multiplot layout 1,3

set view azimuth 0.
set title 'azimuth 0' offset 0,2
splot sample [t=0:20] '+' using (cos($1)):(sin($1)):($1) with lines lw 2

set title 'azimuth 10' offset 0,2
set view azimuth 10.
replot

set title 'azimuth 60' offset 0,2
set view azimuth 60.
replot

unset multiplot```
````

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "only the most recent feed of data is plotted". Is it that you want to keep the previous plot because that data is no longer available in the file, but add new data on top of it?  If the previous data is still in the file, what is the problem with simply re-running your script every ten minutes?

Comment: if this represented my data set:                                                                                 ```# x    y
6.02   153.33
9.59   154.03
9.59   154.03
new data>>10.58   153.22<<                                                                                    ```   if new data is appended to bottom; it reads and plots only the last entry(ie the newly appended data). Do you know how this might be achieved. also show if new data appends from the top instead of the bottom; it better to measure twice so you can cut once.

Answer (score 0):

So each plot will only contain a single point?

Read and plot only the last entry in the file:

```
plot '< tail -1 file.dat' with points
```

Read and plot only the first entry in the file:

```
plot '< head -1 file.dat' with points
```

Be aware that this can only work if the program writing *to* the data file closes it after each write.  If it holds the file open all the time then gnuplot will probably not be able to see any new data.

**Edit:**

3D example reading data from a file:

```
set view equal xy
set zzeroaxis; set xzeroaxis; set yzeroaxis
set xyplane at 0
unset border
unset key
unset xtics
unset ytics
set ztics axis

set arrow 1 from 0,0,0 to graph 1,0,0 head filled lw 1.5
set label 1 at graph 1.1,0,0 "X" center
set arrow 2 from 0,0,0 to graph 0,1,0 head filled lw 1.5
set label 2 at graph 0,1.1,0 "Y" center
set arrow 3 from 0,0,0 to graph 0,0,1 head filled lw 1.5
set label 3 at graph 0,0,1.1 "Z" center

set view 60, 30, 1., 1.75

set multiplot layout 1,3

set view azimuth 0.
set title 'azimuth 0' offset 0,2
splot 'silver.dat' using 1:2:3 with lines lw 2

set title 'azimuth 10' offset 0,2
set view azimuth 10.
replot

set title 'azimuth 60' offset 0,2
set view azimuth 60.
replot

unset multiplot
```

[image]

Comment: hello Ethan, that sounds straight forward, thank you. Do you know how I can modify the code above to read from say a 'file.dat' because at the moment it, produces a static plot from the code given. I would like it to read a file.dat, using data from specifc columns eg. say ``` using 1:6 (data from cloumns 1 and 6)```                                        and the sample/ range can be eg ``` [t=0:100]``` Can you give any pointers. I am a noob on gnuplot.

Comment: The quoted string `'<head -1 file.dat'` substitutes a shell command for a simple file name, but all the other options you mention remain the same. So yeah, you can say `plot [0:100] '< head -1 file.dat' using 1:6 with points`, specifying both a range an a column selection.   The keyword `sample`, however, is not relevant for data plots.

Comment: Please show your actual data and the exact plot command that gave an error.  The error message you quote should only be possible from an `splot` comman, not a `plot` command.

Comment: The code now showing above is taken straight from the azimuth demo, and works fine for me in gnuplot versions 5.2 and 5.4.   Are you saying it doesn't work for you?   Or if you are saying you changed it to read from a file instead, please show the changed version (and also show at least part of the file).

Comment: Sorry, your question is extremely unclear.   Gnuplot is plotting x, y, and z values.  Those values can come from a function (not shown), from a program-generated set of samples (1st example, your code snippet from the demo) or from numbers in a file (2nd example).  Normally the x, y, z values are used as Cartesian coordinates (orthogonal axes).  That is what is used in both examples 1 and 2.   It is true that gnuplot has an option to use the x, y, z values as cylindrical coordinates, but that is not illustrated here. See for example the demo http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/world.html

Comment: so something along the lines splot myfile.dat '+' using (cos($1)):(sin($1)):($1) with lines lw 2; would that produce an output along the line of the demo. The output would be different due to data used?? I tried your code with my data, i get x range no data or x range undefined ..error message. Its no fun being a noob

Comment: Is tail a command recognised by linux/unix only?? or will that work with windows?

Comment: @Randolp if you want to get identical (or similar) functionality like with Linux built-in tools on Windows you could install CoreUtils http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm